# MATLAB - 3D Animation plot

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, 3d

I have a matrix with 4 variables.
I want to plot the results as a 3D surface animation, having 3 of the variables as x,y and z and the 4th variable as time (t).

I imagine the code to be something like:

```
figure(1)
plot4d(Results(:,1), Results(:,2), Results(:,6), Results(:,3))
```

Here is some sample data:

```
    X         Y         t                            Z                     

   -0.1111    1.2670    1.1000    0.0000    0.0000   9.4568
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.2000    0.0000    0.0000   15.9115
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.3000    0.0000    0.0000   18.3639
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.4000    0.0000    0.0000   22.3732
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.5000    0.0000    0.0000   23.3274
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.6000    0.0000    0.0000   23.3389
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.7000    0.0000    0.0000   23.3437
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.8000    0.0000    0.0000   22.0600
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.9000    0.0000    0.0000   23.7531
   -0.1111    1.2670    1.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0
   -0.1111    1.2670    2.1000    0.0000    0.0000         0
   -0.1111    1.2670    2.2000    0.0000    0.0000         0
   -0.1111    1.2670    2.3000    0.0000    0.0000         0
   -0.1111    1.2670    2.4000    0.0000    0.0000         0
   -0.1111    1.2670    2.5000    0.0000    0.0000         0
   -0.1111    1.2670    2.0000    0.0000    0.0000   23.1249
   -0.1111    1.5330    1.1000    0.0000    0.0000   20.7103
   -0.1111    1.5330    1.2000    0.0000    0.0000   40.2953
   -0.1111    1.5330    1.3000    0.0000    0.0000   53.0801
   -0.1111    1.5330    1.4000    0.0000    0.0000   63.1132
```

The goal is to produce a 3D surface plot that varies with time, so that it looks like someone is waving a blanket ;)

Comment: This is not a coding question, it looks like an order ... SO is not a free code writing service. Please show us what you have tried and what is your coding question.

Comment: @Ratbert: My intention was to write a "clear as possible" question. I am currently trying to make an example code with the "movie" function, but I still strugle with getting it right

Comment: What values are  in your time? discrete, something like  [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,...]? Can you show some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If what you plot is a line, then you could just display it frame by frame, pausing between them according to the time stamp (assumed to be in seconds):

```
 x = Results(:,1);
 y = Results(:,2);
 z = Results(:,3);
 t = Results(:,4);
dt = [diff(t);eps]; 

h = axes('Parent', figure());
hold(h, 'off');

for k = 1:numel(t)
        plot3(h, x(1:k), y(1:k), z(1:k), '-*k');
        pause(dt(k));
end;
```

If you want to capture the animation for the movie, check the [MATLAB tutorial page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/record-animation-for-playback.html).

Comment: No, the plot should be a surface. Forgot to mention it in the question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ViharChervenkov It cannot be a surface, if your x, y and z are vectors.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the first problem I have. I will try to reorder the data to the correct format where z is a matrix. Thanks!